# Caused by: java.io.IOException: File already exists

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to save my DataFrame in CSV format. This is a small data set, therefore I use `coalesce(1)`:

```
df.coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).csv(outputPath + "/test.csv")
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: File already exists:s3://test/test.csv/part-00000-c9f8a000-2601-4b83-a6d6-a3f023937fdc-c000.csv
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.create(S3NativeFileSystem.java:617)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:915)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:793)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.create(EmrFileSystem.java:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStream(CodecStreams.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStreamWriter(CodecStreams.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.<init>(CSVFileFormat.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(CSVFileFormat.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.newOutputWriter(FileFormatWriter.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
```

However I can save this DataFrame as a parquet file without any error:

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(outputPath + "/test")
```

How to solve this issue and save my DataFrame in CSV format?

Comment: Can you check that there is no `test/test.csv` file? I don't know for sure but it might be that Spark doesn't want to overwrite file with a folder.